# Adding products from wishlist to cart is giving me 404

Tags: magento-1.8, controllers, form-validation

I am using magento v1.8.1 and foundation template as the basic theme/tempalte.

The problem is:
When I make a wishlist and shared it with the magento default functionality(I haven't done anything to change them)everything is good and the customer get's the email. **BUT** if you try to add the products through the button "Add all items to shopping cart" it takes me to an 404 page.The button "View all wishlist items" is working fine though..

After investigation I find out that magento is using the same technique that it was using for admin on old versions to check the form_key.

So if you go to `Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php`

There is the function  `public function allcartAction()`
and it has the

```
if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
            return;
        }
```

Which is responsible to redirect if the validation fails.If you comment that out the "add to basket" works fine.
So to sum up: How can I pass the form key? Because I guess that's the problem?It doesn't pass the form key..

Thanks

---------------- **EDIT** --------------------------
If you do:

```
$form     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('code');
        Zend_Debug::dump($form);
```

you can get the form key.But not if you try form_key..

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem?

Comment: No to be honest. The solution from Tyler V. seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that this is present in your theme, as Ronwe said:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
```

This seems to be a JavaScript bug that comes in the default theme, and gets copied into custom themes a lot. In \app\design\frontend[YOUR THEME]\default\template\wishlist\view.phtml above

```
setLocation(url);
```

I put

```
url += '&form_key=' + jQuery('#wishlist-view-form input[name="form_key"]').val();
```

and it fixed the issue. I hope that helps.

Comment: ! I do not find setLocation(url) in the view.phtml file. Can you explain little more what do you mean by by the specified line above setLocation

Comment: This depends on your Magento version and which theme you're using. This issue has been fixed in newer versions of Magento. If you're using a custom theme, please post your copy of \app\design\frontend\[YOUR THEME]\default\template\wishlist\view.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Check what template is used for displaying the "allcart" form. You can do it by going to:

- Admin -> System -> Configuration
- changing scope to desired store view
- selecting "Advanced / Developer" tab
- setting "Template Path Hints" to "Yes" in the Debug section

By default it is app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml. If your theme uses different template make sure that within the form it renders the form key:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>
```

Also check in HTML source that the key actually sits within the "allcart" form.

Answer (score 0):

So no one thought it would be wise to mention that form keys are:

- session based
- SHALL be bound to one specific session and thus NOT be shared

The solution is quite simple. Don't share an "add to cart" link. Even if the email is read within the session's expiration time, the form key isn't linked to the session that generated the form key.
Take them to the product page. If your product page is setup correctly, conversion will occur.